# Compare a nullable-int and a string for equality in C#

Tags: c#

I often find reason to compare two values or objects in C# - often different types - and I find myself unhappy with the code I write.
The code ends up looking (to me) verbose and unclear and I frequently end up feeling the need to add a comment that says "//check if they're equal".
(I often blame the fact that that there's no nullsafe-dereference operator like I saw in Groovy once.)

In a recent example, I have two variables:

`string s;

int? i;`

Let's say I want to compare them so that I can do something if they're "obviously equal".
I'm defining them as "obviously equal" if either:
a) the int? doesn't contain a number and the string is null, or else...
b) the string is what you'd get if you wrote out the numerical value of the int? in a plain / unformatted fashion.

[Note that in this case I'm not actually bothered whether the number 1234 is considered equal to the strings "01234" or "1234.00" (or indeed "1234,00", if you're what I consider foreign).
You can have flexibility either way on those as long as "1234" **is** considered equal, and (e.g.) "1233+1" and "1234z" **aren't**.
You can also have flexibility on whether an int? that doesn't contain a number is considered equal to an empty string.]

So, I want some [clear / simple / short - with apologies for the subjectiveness] expression to put in my "if" condition which will perform the check as required above and definitely won't throw an exception.
What are my options?

(If anyone wants to compare their solution to how this might be more easily expressed in other languages, feel free.  It's always useful to know where the greener grass is...)

**UPDATE:**

My own code boils down to something like...

`if (s == (i.HasValue ? i.Value.ToString() : null))`


which actually doesn't look so bad now that s and i aren't meaningfully named properties on other objects.
[However, I don't really like leaving an "==" comparison in there because (though it works for strings because of string-interning and/or an operator override or something) it's normally checking reference equality, right?   So I'd consider replacing that with string.Equals... but that's even more horrible to read.]

When you also have to check the parent objects (on which the "meaningful properties" exist) for null, the code just gets so long-winded - and that's what was on my mind when I posted the question, I think.
I wanted to see whether everybody else had something I was missing.

I really want to be able to simply check for the positive condition and have everything else evaluate to false (without throwing a visible exception).  So...

`if (      (someObject.s == null && someOther.i == null)

        ||

        (int.Parse(someObject.s) == someOther.i)  )`

or similar would be *very* "happy" if all possible (null-ref / parse) exceptions could be silently coerced to false.
I guess I'm just getting too lazy in my old age....

Comment: I would definitely do this check in a separate function, not inside an "if" statement.

Comment: Convert string to int using `int.TryParse` then compare it with `i.Value` with check for `HasValue` and comparing string for `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`....

Comment: Where is your *unhappy code* ?

Comment: This question is a hot mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public static bool ObviouslyEquals<T>(this string  s, T? t) where T: struct
    {
        if (s == null && !t.HasValue)
            return true;
        if (s == null || !t.HasValue)
            return false;
        return s.Equals(t.Value.ToString());
    }


string s;
int? i; 
if (s.ObviouslyEquals(i))...
```

Comment: what is the usefulness of this... ?

Comment: @0A0D it does what the OP wants and code at the call site is clear without a comment.

Comment: Well, it answers the OP's question *"So, I want some [clear / simple / short - with apologies for the subjectiveness] expression to put in my "if" condition which will perform the check as required above and definitely won't throw an exception."*

Comment: I know (I upvoted) but it just seems odd. You seem to be the only one who could understand this

Comment: +1 for the function name `ObviouslyEquals`, as it makes me want to write a function called `UnobviouslyEquals`. ;)

Comment: That'll throw a `NullReferenceException` if `i` is `null` (that is, if the argument `t` of your method is `null`)...  you need more checks.

Comment: @DanPuzey The parameter `t` can't be `null` since it's of type `Nullable<T>` which is a struct.

Comment: @DanPuzey I don't think so. If `i` is `null` it will `return false` in the second `if` statement.

Comment: @DanPuzey No it won't.  `t` is a nullable type.

Comment: @Henrik: that second `if` statement was edited in; I wrote the comment against your original code.  @JohnH/cremor: if you say `int? t = null; t.Value.ToString();` you get a `NullReferenceException`, which is what the original code did.

Comment: @DanPuzey so it took you 9 minutes to write the comment? :)

Comment: @Henrik: it may have taken me that long to post it, yes - I'm at work :P  Apologies for not refreshing first!

Comment: Though it wasn't exactly what I wanted (and hanging such a method off string doesn't feel good, and while the code is indeed clear / simple / short at the call site it's at the expense of having to look elsewhere for the actual details of the comparison ) I do have to admit that it's a literal answer to my question.  Accepted, therefore!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a value "i" can never be (let's say -1), you could use something like this:

```
((object)i ?? -1).ToString() == s
```

This won't work with special number format, though.
So maybe this would help:

```
int x;

!((i == null) != (s == null) || i != null && (!ToInt32.TryParse(s, out x) || i != x))
```

Comment: The first statement appeals to my sensibilities, though '== s' won't suffice when i and s are null, right?  It'll need to be '== (s ?? "-1")', I guess.   And I'll obviously need that value that i can't be.